# Is there any simple way of adding many columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sum

I have a data which consist of different columns, and i want to sum and show in different column (Total)
is there any simple code to do this?
[image]

i did with below formula but imagine if i have 100's of columns. I guess i have to write loop, right?

```
Crime["Total"]=Crime[2001]+ Crime[2002]+ Crime[2003]+ Crime[2004]+ Crime[2005]+ Crime[2006]+ Crime[2007]+ Crime[2008]+ Crime[2009]+ Crime[2010]+ Crime[2011]+ Crime[2012]
```

Comment: You can use regex to column filter the dataframe then use, or column index slicing.

Comment: `Crime.loc[:, 2001:2012].sum(1)`

Comment: If you have non-related, numeric columns in between the columns `2001` and `2012`, prefer `Crime.loc[:, range(2001, 2013)].sum(1)`

Comment: Thanks Scott Boston, Quang Hoang and Rafaelc, its working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `axis=1` to do this:

`Crime['Total'] = Crime.sum(axis=1)`

This ignores the non-numeric columns